# Is there a way to identify mistakes in my code

Tags: r, testing

I subset (having only setosa) from the the dataframe iris:

```
iris[iris$Species=="setosa",]
```

Bellow is an example where `,` is missed, but it can be any other error or typo:

```
iris[iris$Species=="setosa"]
```

How can I identify that I have an error and what the error is?

Comment: An IDE will do that for you or the error given will tell you. Otherwise, writing tests? In the above error for example it tells you "undefined columns selected". Honestly, I'm not sure how you can best find what went wrong but the more code you write(and/or books you read), the more likely you're to know what an error means and/or how to avoid it altogether.

Comment: writing tests? in the sense?

Comment: Writing tests: The art of writing code to test that the code you wrote works as expected. It is more of a "developer" focused strategy.

Comment: Thanks. You meant we need to write the test to check the code? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes but if you're "just" using code, you rarely have to write tests which leaves  "experience" as the best teacher.

Comment: Umm, just read the error message?

Comment: @Roland Yeah, But in case of more errors. For beginners it will be difficult actually

Comment: If you search for the error and flip through a few SO Q&As, you should be fine.

Comment: Everything is difficult for beginners. You get experience, you learn, it becomes easier. We can only try to create verbose and understandable error messages. But it's not possible to anticipate every error and you can't switch everyday language for technical language or you will confuse the experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to using `data.table` because it provides concise interface to data manipulation.

with `data.table` all options bellow work:

```
library(data.table)
iris.dt <- data.table(iris)
iris.dt[Species=="setosa"]
iris.dt[Species=="setosa", ]
iris.dt[iris.dt$Species=="setosa"]
iris.dt[iris.dt$Species=="setosa", ]
```

However, it will not make you code bug free, so have a look at `testthat` package and Test Driven Development (TDD).

Comment: Perfect. Is this what you mean https://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/tests.html

Comment: Yes, which has link to the package itself https://github.com/r-lib/testthat. it integrates well with Rstudio, you have shortcuts to run tests. It also works best when you package your code.